# Crash with localDataStore and PFFacebookUtils

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I just enabled localDataStore. Everything worked fine before, and if I comment it out everything works fine again. I want to do some local persistence, and since I can't use NSCoding for PFRelations to store objects in NSUserDefaults, my best option is localDataStore.

But it's not working.

If I login with Facebook it works fine. However, on the next app launch it crashes on this line:

[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

With the console:

```
-[__NSCFBoolean _loadSensitiveUserDataFromKeychainItemWithName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x37f77660
```

And the trace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xf318, 0x3762cc64 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x3762cc64 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x29e2a038 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 188
    frame #2: 0x29e27f56 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 714
    frame #3: 0x29d59df8 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
    frame #4: 0x00697a4c LY`+[PFUser currentUser](self=<unavailable>, _cmd=<unavailable>) + 532 at PFUser.m:928
    frame #5: 0x00693d14 LY`+[PFUser(self=<unavailable>, _cmd=<unavailable>, provider=0x15d55fb0) registerAuthenticationProvider:] + 116 at PFUser.m:423
  * frame #6: 0x007a5f46 LY`+[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithUrlShemeSuffix:](self=<unavailable>, _cmd=<unavailable>, urlSchemeSuffix=<unavailable>) + 98 at PFFacebookUtils.m:58
    frame #7: 0x000a6f96 LY`-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](self=0x15de8260, _cmd=0x2da83320, application=0x15de5420, launchOptions=0x00000000) + 1190 at AppDelegate.m:139
    frame #8: 0x2d34e720 UIKit`-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 284
    frame #9: 0x2d5435ae UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2358
    frame #10: 0x2d545afa UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1374
    frame #11: 0x2d550378 UIKit`__84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 36
    frame #12: 0x2d544386 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 130
    frame #13: 0x3056b0e8 FrontBoardServices`__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 12
    frame #14: 0x29deb39c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #15: 0x29dea660 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 216
    frame #16: 0x29de8de2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 762
    frame #17: 0x29d37210 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    frame #18: 0x29d37022 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #19: 0x2d3483ee UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 558
    frame #20: 0x2d3431d0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
    frame #21: 0x001310d4 LY`main(argc=1, argv=0x015a3ad0) + 116 at main.m:9
```

Comment: Exactly same problem here !!

Comment: I created a bug on the Parse platform here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/802450039810796/

Answer (score 0):

So, this "feature" seems to be resolved with the update to v1.6.3 of the Parse iOS/OS X SDK.

See [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/802450039810796/) provided by @Numereyes for the discussion and the official response...